# How do I set variables from verbatim shell output?

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables, eval

I thought this should be simple, but now that I'm trying it I can't figure it out. Did I take stupid pills this morning?

I have a command with output that is some variables that I want set. I thought I could use `eval`, but that apparently doesn't work.

Here's what I *want* to do:

```
$ ./foo
FOO=bar
BAR=baz
$ eval ./foo
$ echo $FOO
bar
```

How do I set those directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the output of the script, not the string `./foo`

```
$ eval $( ./foo )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try todo is sourcing the foo file into your shell. You can do that by invoking dot command and give your file as argument (the file does not have to be executable)

```
$ . ./foo
$ echo $FOO
bar
```

Comment: `./foo` doesn't necessarily *set* variables called `FOO` and `BAR`; it simply writes the assignment statements to standard output.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstand question. I understand that foo script contains regular shell commands, not outputing raw text on standard output. If it works in this way, clearly your answer in the right way